# jQuery Gallerrific | Handling a custom parameter for positioning

Tags: jquery, slideshow

The brief is the following for all those who know galleriffic:
I have a numeric value inside a rel attribute on the list of a tags that point to the images.
I have managed to get this number and assocciate it with the imageData object that galleriffic uses to store the image info.
What I cannot do is apply this value using .css() for example into the  tag.
I want to change the padding for each image individually so that I can have the following
output:

OR
change the padding of the 
both have the same result

I cannot find **where** in the javascript code to call the following command to do this:

```
$("#slideshow").css("top",imageData.padd+"px");
```

Here is a link to my example: http://www.44db.com/demo/snf-grands/

Answer (score 0):

after a quick look at your example-page and Galleriffic it seems like you could just add the option `onSlideChange` to your Galleriffic-initialization and add your function there.

```
onSlideChange: function() { $("#slideshow").css("top",imageData.padd+"px"); }
```

Maybe you will have to extract the padding out of the rel-tag within this function, but since you seem to know Galleriffic better than me, this should be no problem for you.